# MySQL JDBC connector not found in jar file

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have been working on project and when i made the jar file and executed it, everything works fine but when the sql connector is called,It gives an error saying mysql driver not found.
I have included mysql connector jar file in the project build path. MySQL function works fine when executed in Eclipse.

Comment: jar -classpath %CLASSPATH%;<path_to_sql_connector>;<path_to_your_jar>  <classname>

Comment: is this a web or desktop application?

Comment: No this is not a web application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Make sure that the Jar file and the Lib directory Containing the Connector Jar are in the same location like this

```
Myjarfile.jar
 libdirectory
        Myconnectorjar.jar
```